# the application could not be loaded on the device

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I have a small problem with an application when I try to install it on a physical device, I can install another application on the device, but that specific one makes me skip that error and a legend appears saying "the application could not be loaded on the device "
Any idea why that happens?
-P.S. I had already installed the application on that device several days ago, but that error just happened.

this only happens with an ios device, with emulators works perfect and with android device also works

this is the output that the compiler gives me:

```
Installing application bundle 'com.onavarro.AppJoynder' on 'iPhone de Jovany Elizalde'

Installing application bundle 'com.onavarro.AppJoynder' on 'iPhone de Jovany Elizalde'
 TransferringPackage - PercentComplete: 10%

 CopyingFile - PercentComplete: 10%
 CopyingFile - PercentComplete: 11%
 .....................
 CopyingFile - PercentComplete: 98%
 CopyingFile - PercentComplete: 98%
 CopyingFile - PercentComplete: 98%
 CopyingFile - PercentComplete: 99%
 CopyingFile - PercentComplete: 99%
 CopyingFile - PercentComplete: 99%
 CopyingFile - PercentComplete: 99%
 CopyingFile - PercentComplete: 99%
 CopyingFile - PercentComplete: 99%
 CopyingFile - PercentComplete: 99%
 CopyingFile - PercentComplete: 99%
 CopyingFile - PercentComplete: 99%
 CreatingStagingDirectory - PercentComplete: 5%
 ExtractingPackage - PercentComplete: 15%
 InspectingPackage - PercentComplete: 20%
 TakingInstallLock - PercentComplete: 20%
 PreflightingApplication - PercentComplete: 30%
 InstallingEmbeddedProfile - PercentComplete: 30%
 VerifyingApplication - PercentComplete: 40%
 ApplicationVerificationFailed: Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.O19Qy5/extracted/AppJoynder.iOS.app : 0xe8008016 (The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.)
error MT1006: Could not install the application '/Users/Jovany/Documents/JOYNDER APP/oscarnavarroc10/joynder.git/AppJoynder.iOS/bin/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone6.1-11.3.1/AppJoynder.iOS.app' on the device 'iPhone de Jovany Elizalde': Your code signing/provisioning profiles are not correctly configured. Probably you have an entitlement not supported by your current provisioning profile, or your device is not part of the current provisioning profile. Please check the iOS Device Log for details (error: 0xe8008016).

No se pudo cargar la aplicación en el dispositivo.
```

Comment: 1)Try to delete your app from device and then install it again;
2) also you have that error "Your code signing/provisioning profiles are not correctly configured. Probably you have an entitlement not supported by your current provisioning profile, or your device is not part of the current provisioning profile." You have to configure your ios bundle signing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at [apple developer](https://developer.apple.com/) at your certificates and code signing / provisioning profiles. Maybe they are invalid or revoked or not created. Without them you can't install your app on a physical device.